# Run select event in scope of the particular form of where was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found similar problems of this topic but nothing I have found helped me and I really feel like this is a dead end, I don't know what to do.

> [[image: I have a page where I can create multiple accounts, that means every time I create an account, a form must be completed and then is saved.]]
> The problem is that when I select another option on a form, it changes on  all the other forms.
> ex: I have saved account on option 1, then I make another one and I select option 2, it changes the above form as well to be on option 2 (only the inputs, the select shows option 1).

HTML - this is some part of the form, I deleted some parts, I have more inputs etc.

```
<form action=".." method="post" class="parsingSettingsForm">
                              
     <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <select class="form-control form-control-sm connType" name="connection_type">
                  <option value="1" <?= $parsing_settings->connection_type && (int)$parsing_settings->connection_type === 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>I Connection</option>
                 <option value="2" <?= $parsing_settings->connection_type && (int)$parsing_settings->connection_type === 2 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>M G Connection</option>
              </select>
          </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-md-4 iconn" style="<?= (int)$parsing_settings->connection_type === 2 ? 'display: none' : '';?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="<?= $parsing_settings->ID ?>"/>
          <input class="form-control input-sm" id="fullname" placeholder="" type="text"
                                           name="server_path"
                                           value="<?= (isset($parsing_settings->server_path) ? $parsing_settings->server_path : '') ?>"/>
                                </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mgconn" style="<?= (int)$parsing_settings->connection_type === 1 ? 'display: none' : '';?>">
           <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" type="text" name="port" value="<?= (isset($parsing_settings->port) ? $parsing_settings->port : '') ?>"/>
                                    
                                </div>
<div class="aright">
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary submitButton" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

and js file:

```
$('form.parsingSettingsForm').closest($("select.connType").off('change').on('change', function () {
                if (Number(this.value) === 1) {
                    $(".mgconn").hide();
                    $('.mgconn input').prop('required', false);
                    $(".iconn").show();
                } else if (Number(this.value) === 2) {
                    $(".mgconn").show();
                    $('.mgconn input').prop('required', true);
                    $(".iconn").hide();
                }
            }));
```

So my guess is that somehow I must change the js function and put some condition that the event apply to the current form I am editing.

!!!UPDATE!!!
Eventually I solved the problem with :

```
$(`.parentdiv`)
        **.on('shown.bs.collapse'**, function () {
            var $collapseDiv = $(this);
        

            $collapseDiv.find('select.connType').off('change').on('change', function () {

                if (Number(this.value) === 1) {
                    $collapseDiv.find(".mgconn").hide();
                    $collapseDiv.find('.mgconn input').prop('required', false);
                    $collapseDiv.find(".iconn").show();
                    $collapseDiv.find(inputServerPath).prop('required', true);
                } else if (Number(this.value) === 2) {
                    $collapseDiv.find(".mgconn").show();
                    $collapseDiv.find('.mgconn input').prop('required', true);
                    $collapseDiv.find(".iconn").hide();
                    $collapseDiv.find(inputServerPath).prop('required', false);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your callback function you'll need to pull out the parent element and operate within that. I don't believe your HTML has enough detail to completely answer this, but the general idea is this. `.form-group.row` is my best guess as to where you want to operate

```js
function() {
  const accountElement = $(this).closest('.form-group.row');
    if (Number(this.value === 1) {
      accountElement.find('.mgconn').hide();
      // additional changes using accountElement instead of $
```

When jQuery triggers this handler, `this` is set to the object that received the change event. I do not recall if `this` is actually a jQuery object or an HTMLElement. But by wrapping it with `$(this)` we ensure it is a jQuery object and can then access the `.closest` function to search up the DOM tree and find the nearest `.form-group.row` so we can then find children later such as `.mgconn` that are only inside of the current `.form-group.row`. Again, this may not be exactly what you need to do. There doesn't seem to be enough HMTL in the example to provide an exact answer.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thank you, I ll try something like this but please, could you explain me this line $(this).closest('.form-group.row');, to what $(this) is refering to? I have read the difference between this and $(this) but I don't understand...

Comment: I was thinking the form is the parent element, you say .form-group.row because I must take every div of where the inputs .iconn and .mgconn are?